# Different combinations of the following

Tags: combinatorics

To find the number of different signals that can be generated by arranging at-least 2 flags in order (one below the other) on a vertical staff, if five different flags are available.

Now first of all, i din't get the question.There should be the combinations of two flags or all five?I mean 2 flags or 5 flags in a row?

And how to do it?Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flags are arranged in some order. So red above blue, then green is a signal different from blue, then green, then red.

We are free to use $2$ flags, or $3$ flags, or $4$, or $5$.

We calculate how many arrangements of $3$ flags there are. The top flag can be chosen in $5$ ways. For each such choice, the next flag can be chosen in $4$ ways, and for each choice of first $2$ flags, the third can be chosen in $3$ ways, for a total of $(5)(4)(3)$ signals.

Do the same sort of thing for $2$ flags, $4$ flags, $5$ flags, and add up.